# Whitelist an address in Trend IMSS 5.7

Tags: email, spam-filter, attachment

Trying to whitelist an incoming address in Trend IMSS v5 - in practice, emails from this address will have an attachment & we want the message / attachment to bypass the existing 'executable attachments' rule.  Have copied from an existing (working) whitelist rule, but for reasons I can't see the new rule is failing to match & emails from sender are then triggering the subsequent 'executable attachments' rule.

Rule created as follows, and ordered ahead of the the 'executable attachments' rule: 
Global Policy -> Create New Filter -> Advanced Content Filter

Set to match on Mail Header -> From, with a single expression to check.  Have tested this expression both with the full email address of the required sender & wildcard for the domain, eg:
joebloggs@sender.com
*@sender.com

...but neither form is matching the sender.  I'm probably missing something obvious here, but currently drawing a blank.  Would appreciate any suggestions on what I haven't considered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted after some further digging around.  Seemed I was coming at the problem from the wrong angle.  Solution was:
- create Address Group for the addresses to be 'whitelisted'
- add a Sub-policy & routing for the Address Group & required recipients
- disable the attachments policy for that sub-policy only.
Tested and working.